# Angularjs filter orderby numbers and alphabets

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to order by 'displayName'. Sometimes displayName has all numbers or alphabets. $filter('orderBy') is working fine for alphabets. But numbers are rendering like this.

```
1,13,2,23,3,43.
```

How can I filter for numbers and alphabets?

```
    vm.temp=[{id:15, displayName:'ff'},
    {id:2, displayName:'f'},
    {id:10, displayName:'cc'},
    {id:3, displayName:'aa'},
    {id:5, displayName:'h'},
    {id:8, displayName:'y'}]
OR
   vm.temp=[{id:15, displayName:'3'},
    {id:2, displayName:'2'},
    {id:3, displayName:'43'},
    {id:5, displayName:'13'},
    {id:8, displayName:'1'},
 {id:9, displayName:'23'}]

    vm.items = $filter('orderBy')(vm.temp, 'displayName');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the sorter function:

```
function sorter(a) {
  if(isNaN(parseInt(a.displayName))) {
    return a.displayName;
  }
  else {
    return parseInt(a.displayName);
  }
}
```

Update the last line of your code with this:

```
vm.items = $filter('orderBy')(vm.temp, sorter);
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/OfNpqSv3Pj9CDD3bMyoQ?p=streamer

Comment: your logic failed with data like [ {id:15, displayName:'a'}, {id:2, displayName:'b'}, {id:3, displayName:'xyz'}, {id:5, displayName:'m'}, {id:8, displayName:'1'}, {id:9, displayName:'23'} ]

Comment: @user3194721 i have updated the plnkr. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use in on the other side which is HTML.

```
  <p ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy:'displayName'">{{employee}}</p>
```

And check out this also please, even though it is the string, the sorting is working in both the ways.

DEMO: https://codepen.io/mkarrfan/pen/QqOaPa

Answer (score 0):

Use simple javascript and [this script by Brian Huisman based on David koelle's](http://web.archive.org/web/20130826203933/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288)

```
yourarr.sort(function naturalSorter(as, bs){
var a, b, a1, b1, i= 0, n, L,
rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
if(as=== bs) return 0;
a= as.displayName.toLowerCase().match(rx);
b= bs.displayName.toLowerCase().match(rx);
L= a.length;
while(i<L){
    if(!b[i]) return 1;
    a1= a[i],
    b1= b[i++];
    if(a1!== b1){
        n= a1-b1;
        if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
        return a1>b1? 1:-1;
    }
}
return b[i]? -1:0;
```

});

[Here is working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fl7ClIp9DVStTRgYlwTQ?p=preview)